# How to remove round corners in jQuery Mobile? 

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

How to remove the round edges (border-radius) from the particular element or from div tag that is using jQuery Mobile?

[image: Jquery mobile round edges]

Comment: you need to remove the class "ui-btn-corner-all", or only the specific corners, right-click -> inspect element, see what classes it has and when you initialize your element, also remove the corner class

Comment: I think you should not modify existing CSS, either override it by own. The goal of framework is not make it "look similar" on different devices and platforms. As it should be rounded, keep it. Otherwise create you own control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the jQuery mobile CSS file [linked here](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.css), search for this string:

`.ui-corner-tr {`

I don't know if you're even using the default styles, but there's what I found based on the info you provided.

You should be able to change all four corners in that area (as `.ui-corner-tr`, `.ui-corner-tl`, `.ui-corner-br`, `.ui-corner-bl`, etc., etc.)

Answer (score 54):

Talking about buttons, you can apply following option to a button.

```
data-corners="false"
```

A code goes like this:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false">push me</a>
```

The document is here:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html

Thanks.

Comment: this works for my listviews also: <ul data-role = 'listview'  
             data-inset="true"
             data-theme ="e" 
             data-corners="false"                                       
     >

Comment: This is probably a cleaner solution than modifying the stylesheets, this way the styling stays accurate if the jquery files are updated.

Answer (score 6):

In your css file (any) :

```
.ui-corner-all {
   -webkit-border-radius:.0 !important;
   border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```