# How to remove round corners of buttons (jQuery Mobile)?

Tags: css, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I tried the [answers in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463300/how-to-remove-round-corners-in-jquery-mobile).  However, it doesn't work.  I tried adding `data-corners="false"` to the `ul` tag.  I also added this CSS to the `RadioButtonList`:

```
.list-rb div{
    margin-top: -16px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
}
```

I also added `ui-corner-tr` to the `RadioButtonList CssClass`.  No luck.  Is there a way to do this?  Is there something in my HTML or CSS that is preventing me from doing this correctly?

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true" data-corners="false">
    <li data-theme="a" data-role="list-divider" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-b">
        <asp:Localize ID="locWirelessNetworks" runat="server"
            EnableViewState="False" meta:resourcekey="locWirelessNetworksRc1"
            Text="Select Network">
        </asp:Localize>
    </li>
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblWirelessNetworks" runat="server" cssclass="list-rb">
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</ul>
```

[image]

**EDIT**:  I am using jQuery-Mobile 1.3

Comment: I don't have any idea about your asp markup, however as a side note `<br />` is not a valid child of `<ul>` element.

Comment: @HashemQolami It works for me?  Wouldn't that make it valid?  All of the above HTML is in a `asp:Content`

Comment: "Wouldn't that make it valid?" Nope...it might work in one browser but not another and even if it did...it still wouldn't be valid.

Comment: @Paulie_D  That's odd.  I'll remove it then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using jQuery Mobile version 1.3 or lower.

So try removing border radius and margin on the LABEL element within the .ui-radio class:

```
.ui-radio label {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Then you can also remove padding and border on the LI itself too:

```
li {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: 0  !important;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9m3xk2dL/)**

NOTE: we may need to see the rendered HTML from the ASP.Net RadioButtonList control...

Comment: This worked!  Good catch on the old version.  I completely forgot to check that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The sollution is easier then you would think. Add this to your CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type:square;
}
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle then: http://jsfiddle.net/g30rmufy/1/
It's the code you added in your question + the code from my answer. Is this what you were looking for?